# xmpp Framework - detection of changing roster list

Tags: ios, web, xmpp, social-networking, xmppframework

How can I detect that my roster list was changed, some body added or removed?

I use that code to get roster list on startup

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq
{
DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@ - %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD, [iq elementID]);

NSXMLElement *queryElement = [iq elementForName: @"query" xmlns: @"jabber:iq:roster"];
if (queryElement)
{
    NSArray *itemElements = [queryElement elementsForName: @"item"];
    //[self.cts removeAllObjects];
    for (int i=0; i<[itemElements count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *jid = [[[itemElements objectAtIndex:i] attributeForName:@"jid"] stringValue];
        [self.cts addObject:jid];
    }
    NSLog(@"\nRoster ID's %@",self.cts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) All subsequent roster changes will be "pushed" to you with IQ packets contains "jabber:iq:roster" payload, you need to track "subscription" attribute of received items and make changes to your model.
2) XMPPFramework already contains XMPPRoster extension, which do all the job for you, just activate extension, see XMPPFramework examples.